# C# ignoring spaces in search Pattern

Tags: c#

I do have search pattern for Regex, but my multiple file have different number of spaces between them. So I need to ignore them in my pattern.

```
const string PATTERN = @"OTPM              = true";
```

Can someone modify this line for me? I tried different solutions which I found here, but didnt work, since I am  a bit new to C#

Comment: Wouldn't `OTPM *= true` work?

Comment: Do you try this: `OTPM\s+= true`?

Comment: what does ignoring actually mean? what is your expected output? Do you intend to match the line as it is including the whitespaces? or do you intend to get them removed in the output?

Comment: I sort ini files to listbox depenting OTPM is true or false. But multiple ini files have different number of spaces.

Answer (score 0):

```
OTPM\s+= true
```

Worked perfectly fine. Thank you very much, for all responses